# How to decrease the Q-factor of a resonator?

Tags: optics, laser, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

I was trying to create a mode-locked laser in order to create high-intensity light pulses, this experiment was done a while ago and with someone else, and in our notes says that the laser cavity's q-factor was changed in order to lower the rate of energy loss in the resonator.
I don't seem to understand how the q-factor was changed, what can be done in a laser cavity in order to change its q-factor (decrease it in this case).

Thank you for your help and I am sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.rp-photonics.com/q_factor.html?s=ak to better understand the Q-factor. To change the Q-factor of a resonator, you can play with the loss or the lenght of the resonator.

Comment: I had read it, but I thought the q-factor was what influenced the resonator's loss and not the other way around. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q factor of a laser resonator is a *description* of the quality of the resonator.  It is inversely related to the fraction of energy that leaks out through the laser mirrors in each cycle, so that a photon in a high-Q resonator will make a large number of bounces back and forth between mirrors before it has a high likelihood of making it out through the output mirror.

Similarly, Q factor relates to the ratio of beam intensity inside the resonator, to the intensity of the emitted beam.

Though Q factor can be influenced by factors internal to the cavity such as the alignment of Brewster windows, it is primarily affected by the reflectivity of the mirrors.  Higher reflectivity gives higher Q.  You can select laser mirrors according to their reflectivity at your laser's emission wavelength.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it makes much more sense now. Thank you